# std::bad_alloc error trying to run gatsby dev server on a Docker container

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker

I'm trying to run a newly created gatsby app's dev server in a Docker container. I created the app using `gatsby-starter-blog` (https://www.gatsbyjs.com/starters/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog/). My Docker configuration is as follows:

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

EXPOSE 8000

RUN \
  apk add --no-cache python3 make g++ && \
  apk add vips-dev fftw-dev --update-cache \
  --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community \
  --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main \
 && rm -fR /var/cache/apk/*

RUN apk add automake autoconf libtool nasm

RUN npm install -g gatsby-cli

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./package.json ./package-lock.json /app
RUN npm install

COPY . /app
CMD ["gatsby", "develop", "-H", "0.0.0.0", "--verbose"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - GATSBY_WEBPACK_PUBLICPATH=/
```

.dockerignore

```
.cache/
*cache*
```

But when I run `docker compose up --build` I get the following error:

```
[+] Building 12.8s (13/13) FINISHED                                                                                                                               
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring context: 56B                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:lts-alpine                                                                                           1.1s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                            1.7s
 => => transferring context: 4.18MB                                                                                                                          1.6s
 => [1/8] FROM docker.io/library/node:lts-alpine@sha256:a136ed7b0df71082cdb171f36d640ea3b392a5c70401c642326acee767b8c540                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [2/8] RUN   apk add --no-cache python3 make g++ &&   apk add vips-dev fftw-dev --update-cache   --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/  0.0s
 => CACHED [3/8] RUN apk add automake autoconf libtool nasm                                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [4/8] RUN npm install -g gatsby-cli                                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [5/8] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [6/8] COPY ./package.json ./package-lock.json /app                                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [7/8] RUN npm install                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [8/8] COPY . /app                                                                                                                                        6.9s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                       3.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                      3.0s
 => => writing image sha256:a216d00a614b1695c521585fda41fbca38c8b625dcd6fec89e2059419d56e3d4                                                                 0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/gatsby-starter-blog-web                                                                                                   0.0s

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
[+] Running 2/2
 ⠿ Network gatsby-starter-blog_default  Created                                                                                                              0.1s
 ⠿ Container gatsby-starter-blog-web-1  Created                                                                                                              4.7s
Attaching to gatsby-starter-blog-web-1
gatsby-starter-blog-web-1  | ╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
gatsby-starter-blog-web-1  | ║                                                                        ║
gatsby-starter-blog-web-1  | ║   Gatsby collects anonymous usage analytics                            ║
gatsby-starter-blog-web-1  | ║   to help improve Gatsby for all users.                                ║
gatsby-starter-blog-web-1  | ║                                                                        ║
gatsby-starter-blog-web-1  | ║   If you'd like to opt-out, you can use `gatsby telemetry --disable`   ║
gatsby-starter-blog-web-1  | ║   To learn more, checkout https://gatsby.dev/telemetry                 ║
gatsby-starter-blog-web-1  | ║                                                                        ║
gatsby-starter-blog-web-1  | ╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
^[[56;162Rgatsby-starter-blog-web-1  | verbose set gatsby_log_level: "verbose"
verbose set gatsby_executing_command: "develop"
verbose loading local command from:
gatsby-starter-blog-web-1  | /app/node_modules/gatsby/dist/commands/develop.js
verbose running command: develop
gatsby-starter-blog-web-1  | 
gatsby-starter-blog-web-1  | verbose Transition to "initializing"

gatsby-starter-blog-web-1  |  ERROR #11903  API.TYPESCRIPT.COMPILATION
gatsby-starter-blog-web-1  | 
gatsby-starter-blog-web-1  | There was an unhandled error during compilation for /app. Please run the command
gatsby-starter-blog-web-1  |  with the --verbose flag again.
gatsby-starter-blog-web-1  | std::bad_alloc
gatsby-starter-blog-web-1  | 

gatsby-starter-blog-web-1  | 
gatsby-starter-blog-web-1  |   Error: std::bad_alloc
gatsby-starter-blog-web-1  | 
not finished compile gatsby files - 0.136s
gatsby-starter-blog-web-1  | 
gatsby-starter-blog-web-1 exited with code 1
```

Why am I getting a `std::bad_alloc` error? How can I fix this?

I tried adding the `.cache` folder to .Dockerignore and see if that makes the problem go away but without success.

Comment: std::bad_alloc usually means something written in C++ used too much RAM, and you ran out. how much RAM do you have on the system you run `docker compose up --build` on?

Comment: @hanshenrik I'm running on a 16GB MacBook Pro (14-inch, 2021)

Comment: 16GB sounds like a comfortable amount of RAM fwiw. what do you get if you add ```CMD ["free"]``` above ```CMD ["gatsby", "develop", "-H", "0.0.0.0", "--verbose"]```  ?

Comment: @hanshenrik I don't see any difference when adding `CMD ["free"]`.

Comment: really? you don't get a line saying ```[+] Running 2/3```  ?